# Index type error when transforming object

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to transform an object which has arrays as it's value and numbers as it's keys and change the values to the length of the array.

However I get a type error which says 'Element implicity has an any type because an element of type string can't be used to index an {}'
I'm not clear why it is insisting the key is a string type when it's a number.

The code is:

```
  const agentOccupancy = Object.entries(agentOccupiedServicesAndQueues).reduce(
        (obj, [key, value]) => {
          obj[key] = value.length;
          return obj;
        },
        {},
      );
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: `Object.entries` and `Object.keys` always return a `string`

Comment: But the `on type '{}'` refers to the variable `obj` which you created as `{}` in your `reduce`, so you need to assign some type to that in order to set any properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Object.entries` and `Object.keys` **always** return a `string`.  You will get `string` representations of the numeric keys of your object.

```
Object.keys(["a", "b", "c"]); // an array with number keys
--> ["0", "1", "2"] // console output is an array of strings
```

The second part of you error, "can't be used to index type '{}'", refers to the type of the accumulator in your `.reduce()` callback.  You started with an initial value `{}` and that is all that Typescript knows, so it complains when you set any property which is not on `{}`.

We need to assign a type to the accumulator in order to fix this.  The type we will use is `Record<string | number, number>` which says that any `string` or `number` will return a value, and that value is always a `number`.

```
const agentOccupancy = Object.entries(agentOccupiedServicesAndQueues).reduce(
  (obj: Record<string | number, number>, [key, value]) => {
    obj[key] = value.length;
    return obj;
  },
  {}
);
```

The `agentOccupancy` object actually looks like this: `{ "0": 1 }`.  But you can use either `string` keys like `"0"` or `number` keys like `0` to access the value.

```
console.log(agentOccupancy["0"]);
console.log(agentOccupancy[0]);
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/WJ9yVm)